# How to create a dictionary where the keys are all the week numbers within a year and values as lists of the dates of each weekday within a week?

Tags: python, datetime

I am creating a calendar for a schedule.

How would I go about creating a dictionary containing the week number's of a year as key's and the value's would be a list of all the dates of days for that given week.

I want to create a loop to achieve the following.

1 Get each week of the year.

2 Get week days of each week and convert them to their dates and put 
them into a list like such

```
  weekdays ['20/05/2019', '21/05/2019', '22/05/2019', '23/05/2019', 
            '24/05/2019', '25/05/2019', '26/05/2019']
```

3 Create new key and value for the weeks dictionary using the weeknumber as key and the weekdays as the value.

```
 weeks[weeknum] = weekdays
```

The contents of the weeks dictionary would look like this but with all 52 weeks.

```
 weeks {22: weekdays, 23: weekdays... etc}
```

I can get a weeknumber and a weekday of a given date using isocalander but this wouldn't be enough to achieve what I want to do.

What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: What about the single day following week 52?

Comment: @NChauhan From my understanding of the isocalander function, it would count that extra day as week 1 of the next year but week 1 of current year will have the extra day or two from previous year depending on if it was a leap year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd iterate over the days in a year and then add them to a list for each week number. If you use defaultdict, you can do that without having to initialize the dict for the week numbers:

```
import datetime
from collections import defaultdict

date = datetime.date(2019, 1, 1)
enddate = datetime.date(2019, 12, 31)
days_in_each_week = defaultdict(list)

while date < enddate:
    days_in_each_week[date.isocalendar()[1]].append(date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
    date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)

print(days_in_each_week)
```